# session expires randomly in php

Tags: php, session, server

session expires unexpectedly/randomly, how can I fix that. please help me. It's running well on localhost but when I upload it to the server after login session expired randomly.
When I log in and working on that after some time (1-2 minutes) session automatically expired.
"My PHP Version 5.6.28 (on the server)"

Comment: What are you considering random? Is it expiring after you browse through different pages? Does the domain name change at all in the URL when it expires? Or is it expiring after a certain amount of time? If so, is what's the range of time you've seen so far? Is one example of it expiring after 1 minute and then another example is expiring after 3 days? Is this a shared server or a private server? Is there any other activity that might be cleaning up the session directory on the server (often times the /tmp folder)? Do you regenerate session IDs? Have you run Fiddler to capture the problem?

Comment: When I log in and working on that after some time (1-2 minutes) session automatically expired.

Comment: Okay, that's one question answered...

Comment: If you answer the remaining questions, that would help.